# NODE JS basic REQUEST() - how to get response values and concatenate into my res.send()?

Tags: node.js, api, request

A beginners question about NODE JS usage of request() - 
I built this very simple code of my API to response for an HTTP post which uses REQUEST() to another invoke external API.

I am not sure how to get the proper value of my API res.send() based on the request() outcome to the external API.

Here is a simplified code of what I have -

```
app.post('/v1/do', function (req, res) {
    var options = 
    { 
        method: 'PUT', url:`EXTERNAL_API`...
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);              
    });

  // this is where I need help...
  res.send(NEED_TO_GET_REQUEST()_VALUES/OUTCOME);

})
```

I don't know how to get data from the request() function into the res.send().

Thanks in advance :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send response in the callback of request function, like this:

```
app.post('/v1/do', function (req, res) {
    var options = 
    { 
        method: 'PUT', url:`EXTERNAL_API`...
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(500).send(error);
      }     

      res.status(200).send(body);
    });      

})
```